# Как ограничить вывод sub item`a в ListView 3-мя строками?

Tags: java, android, массивы, xml

У меня есть `ListView`. Я вывожу туда некоторые значения из базы данных, но иногда они бывают слишком большими.

Я хочу ограничить количество выводимых строк или символов и в конце дополнять это все троеточием...

Возможно есть какой-то способ сделать это в разметке? Или же придется что-то делать с массивом из БД?

```
userCursor =  db.rawQuery("select * from "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DATECATEGORY, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NOTE};
userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
header.setText("Всего записей: " + String.valueOf(userCursor.getCount()));
mList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать собственную разметку в адаптере и в ней для TextView прописать

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Так текст будет ограничен одной строкой и, если не влезает, будет оканчивается многоточием